# Python library to draw a Tree structure in a html document?

Tags: javascript, python, tree

I'm asking this question because I haven't been able to find a Python library to draw a Tree to an html document, do you know any?

If there aren't any out there, what would you recommend to do?

I'm extracting the data from an sql database, then I thought it would be a good idea to format it into a json or some sort of language compatible file and then give it to a JS library such as the ones stated in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058073/how-do-i-draw-a-graph-or-tree-structure-in-javascript).

[Expected output](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBinary_tree&psig=AOvVaw0cmXLvkUtlDflOdvxVs_YS&ust=1670425298861000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCPj1y6Sh5fsCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAX) (answering to @trincot comment): whereas instead of numbers in the nodes I'm going to store a medium long text in it.

Comment: This is too broad. Please provide sample input and the corresponding output you expect in HTML and what you have tried.

Comment: Why do you think this is too broad?
I just asked for a py library to store a Tree Drawing.

If you're asking instead what type of Tree then it's gotta be a Btree.
I'm going to store integer ids and some other info in it.
The condition to differentiate r-l child nodes is actually not relevant to the question.

I didn't try anything, as stated in the question I'm as for right now looking for a library before proceeding to write any code.
As for the "expected output of the tree" I've included a link in the question because the comment is far too small to include it.

Comment: Asking for a library is off topic too. (NB: a B-tree and a binary tree are two different data structures).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to solve ypu problem with python:
https://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And you can use these js libraries to draw tree structure:
https://www.cssscript.com/best-tree-view/

Comment: I already had seen Treelib but it doesn't seem to have support to store data into an html document tho...

Comment: Which library do you use to printing html? Django or flask? You can use java script regex to modify it.